# Session Value Not Transferring From Root Directory

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a login page in my website in the root directory. After successful login this code is executed.
`$class = $x['class'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
header("location:/$class");` 
`$class` can be values between 6-12 and I have a separate directory for each of 'em. Now after going to any subdirectory, `$_SESSION['email']` is lost.
 I also have a session called theme which is used to change the colour of my website and can be changed from any page. Now say I change `$_SESSION['theme']` in /6/index.php and went to /7/index.php, the value won't get lost. but if I go to /index.php the value of `$_SESSION['theme']` is lost. 
But after that 
If I go to /10/index.php, the value is retrieved again.

So to summarize, the session value is transferred between the subdirectories. But is not transferred between root and subdirectories.

What should I do? I am sure I typed `session_start();` at the beginning of every page. 

Thnx In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by copying the files from the root directory to a folder called root and did a 301 redirect from /index.php to /root/index.php. Not a recommended solution though